# Uniform Manifold Approximation and Projection (UMAP)

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, machine-learning

Can someone please help to give a detailed but not too complicated in-depth explanation of the steps of UMAP graph formation without losing any important information ? I understand the overall idea of conserving global structure using its parameters, and the idea of graphing using distances, but its extremely hard to find any summarized mathematical information out there, please help, thank you.

```
import umap
n_n = 2

umap_model_1 = umap.UMAP(n_components=n_n)
umap_result_1 = umap_model_1.fit_transform(test_np)

plt.xlabel('UMAP 1')
plt.ylabel('UMAP 2')
plt.show()
```

This is the UMAP process in Python I have been introduced too

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.